# svn on apache server - accessing the old repos is giving the error

Tags: svn

Hope someone can help me on this. I have looked for this online, but couldn't get the solution.
I already had the server setup with the svn subversion. Now I have re-installed the OS (all the old repos are still intact) and tried to setup the svn again. I am able to create a new repo and access it via webserver, but when I try accessing the old repos, I am getting an error, mentioned below.

**"This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.


Could not open the requested SVN filesystem "**

Can someone please help me with this on how get my old repos to work?

Regards,
Gopi

Comment: What version of Subversion server was installed before OS reinstall? What version is installed now? How did you configure the server?

Comment: The current version is -  1.6.11. But I am unsure on previous version. This was released on Aug 2015, so probably it was same version earlier, as the my previous installation was in 2016.  Do you mean the http server or SVN server? The svn server was configured by modifying the /etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf file. I am actually able to create a new repository and access it. But the problem is I am unable to access the old ones which were created before the server was re-installed. Thanks -

Comment: Check your server's log. The log should have relevant events that explain the root cause. I guess that your repositories have newer format that SVN 1.6 (which is very old and is no longer supported) does not understand. Use SVN 1.9.